# Tkinter - Underline only letters in Labels?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

```
a = Label(root,text='h e l l o',underline=0)
```

So basically I want to be able to choose which parts of the string I want to underline. Right now it only lets me choose one at a time. If I try:

```
a = Label(root,text='h e l l o',underline=0,1)
```

I get the error:

```
a = Label(root,text='h e l l o',underline=0,2)
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

I have looked at other posts and they suggest making a font to make the whole string underlined. I want to make just the letters underlined. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The point of the `underline=` option is to indicate what the keystroke equivalent is for activating a button or other clickable object.  As such, it would be meaningless to underline more than one character.  I believe your only option for underlining arbitrary characters would be a read-only Text widget, in which case you could style each character individually.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple character underlining is possible with unicode '\u0332' (underline of previous character).  This avoids using the underline styling of the tkinter Label widget and allows multiple items to be underlined. To make *just* the letters underlined, use list comprehension and `isalpha()` to identify the letters. In the example below, the required text is moved to a string (`mylabel`) and preprocessed using:

```
mylabel='h e l l o'
utext=''.join([letter+'\u0332' if letter.isalpha() else letter for letter in mylabel])
a = Label(root,text=utext)
```

The above was tested on Python 3.7 on Windows 10. Note the previous [limitations identifed with using unicode '\u0332'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51001592/how-to-underline-text-in-python-3-6-5) on some platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Your choice with a `Label` is to underline a single character with the `underline` option, or to underline the entire string by using a font with `underline` option turned on.

The text widget allows you to underline individual characters, so my recommendation is to use a single-line text widget, or to use a canvas widget with multiple text items for each group of characters that are to be underlined or not.

Comment: So I looked a bit into the text widgets and it looks like you need to set tags for it. Can you provide an example?