# how to underline text in python 3.6.5

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

How can I print underlined text similar to what is shown on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underline#Unicode) in python? What unicode characters would I give to python to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, arbitrary unicode characters can be expressed with `\uXXXX` where XXXX is a four-digit hex number identifying the code point.

Wikipedia shows the use of "combining low line" (U+0332).

Since it's a combining character, you need to place it *after* each character you want to be underlined.

So this code should print `aaau̲zzz` (`u` should be underlined in most browsers).

```
print('aaau\u0332zzz')
```

---

Note that this doesn't seem to work very well.

My `gnome-terminal` (which identifies as `GNOME Terminal 3.26.2 Using VTE version 0.50.3 +GNUTLS`), using `Monospace Regular` font, mis-renders the underline on the *following* character:

[image]

But if I copy the resulting text and paste it onto Stack Overflow, it seems to render correctly (Chrome on Linux):

> aaau̲zzz

Unless I format it as code:

```
aaau̲zzz
```

In which case it doesn't "combine" at all.

Here's a screenshot of the above, in case your browser renders it differently:

> [image]

Comment: How do I get the underline to show up under the character though?

Comment: Proper rendering likely depends on your terminal, font, etc.

Comment: Interestingly, on Windows and Chrome this answer renders `aaauzzz` with the `u` underlined in your copy/paste, but code format it underlines the first `z`.  If I edit your question, the rendering below the edit window is **correct** for both.  Rendering is inconsistent in the same browser, much less different ones :^)

Comment: Firefox on Windows renders the `u̲` in the code block properly https://imgur.com/a/Kugov8R However Edge renders the underline on the z character