# Why will Unicode '\u0332' not underline space '\u0020'?

Tags: python

Combining the answers on [How to underline text in python 3.6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51001592/how-to-underline-text-in-python-3-6-5) with a list comprehension will let me underline an entire word using [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underline#Unicode) underline `'\u0332'` like this:

```
# In[1]:
str1 = 'abc'
str1 = ''.join([s+'\u0332' for s in str1])
print(str1)

# Out[1]:
'a̲b̲c̲'
```

This will ***not*** work for strings with **spaces**:

```
# In[2]:
str2 = 'ab c'
str2 = ''.join([s+'\u0332' for s in str2])
print(str2)

# Out[2]:
'a̲b̲ ̲c̲'
```

And I would be perfectly OK with that if it were the case that `' '` was not recognized somehow. But that does not seem to be the whole problem here, since using space unicode `'\u0020'` does not resolve the issue using an approach like this:

```
# In[3]:

str3 = 'ab c'
str4 = [s+'\u0332' if s != ' ' else '\u0020'+'\u0332' for s in str3]
str5=''.join(str4)
print(str5)

# Out[3]:
'a̲b̲ ̲c̲'
```

Still no success. But the really interesting thing here is that printing str4 to the console will give you this:

```
#In[4]:
print(str4)

#Out[4]:
['a̲', 'b̲', ' ̲', 'c̲']
```

Running `str4[2]` will even return this: `' ̲'`! And it's impossible to see here, but when printed in the IPython console, the 'missing' underline appears under `C`:

[image]

What's going on here? Is this a bug, or am I trying to accomplish something that just wasn't mean to be?

Comment: The linked answer says `Note that this doesn't seem to work very well.` and explains *why* that happens - different terminals, different fonts will display the text differently

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I know different terminals and different fonts will display the text differently. But to my knowledge, none will show an underlined space, and I still think that's very, very weird. So in my humble opinion I don't think the linked question has a full explanation as to ***why*** this happens.

Comment: I have no idea why you think that using `\u0020` would do anything. Do you realive that `\u0020` is **exactly the same** as just `' '`? `20` base 16 is `32` and `' '` is the ASCII character of code 32. In fact the python parser& compiler will even use the same object instance: `>>> '\u0020' is ' ' -->
True`  (note: it's not just `==` it's `is`!).

Comment: I suspected that  `\u0020` somehow would be recognized as a character and `' '` would not, and that that woould place the underline in the correct place.

Comment: I would have instinctively said that a space isn't a valid thing to combine with a combining character, but looking at [Unicode standard 12.0, section 3.6](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode12.0.0/UnicodeStandard-12.0.pdf#G6.52439), it looks like a space actually *is* a valid base character to begin a combining character sequence. I'm not sure whether it counts as a valid grapheme base, though, or the specific intended handling for this combining character, or your font's font-specific handling.

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you! That is valuable information. And I think the issue just got even a little weirder.

Comment: I would have suggested to substitute space with "_", but that does not match in printing...

`>>>a̲b̲_c̲`

This does tho : '\uff3f' `>>>a̲b̲＿c̲` But it is a long underline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround. Instead of unicode, you can use ANSI escape sequence:

```
str2 = 'ab c'
str2 = ''.join(['\033[4m'+s for s in str2 ])
print(str2)
```

But just displays in the python console.

Comment: The character sequences you're sending here are instructions for a terminal or terminal emulator. They will not work when processed by a browser, a text editor, or anything else that isn't at least pretending to be a terminal.